# Accessing the Selenium api in R

Tags: r, selenium

I am interested in using selenium with R. I note that the various documentation is described here [WebDriver (Selenium 2) API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644868/webdriver-selenium-2-api-documentation). Has there been any work done on an implementation with R. How would I go about approaching this. In the documentation it notes about running a selenium server and one can query the api using Javascript. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium can be accessed using the [JsonWireProtocol](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol).

Firstly start up a Selenium server from the command line via:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar
```

a new Firefox browser can be opened as follows:

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
library(XML)

baseURL<-"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/"
server<-list(desiredCapabilities=list(browserName='firefox',javascriptEnabled=TRUE))

getURL(paste0(baseURL,"session"),
       customrequest="POST",
       httpheader=c('Content-Type'='application/json;charset=UTF-8'),
       postfields=toJSON(server))

serverDetails<-fromJSON(rawToChar(getURLContent('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/sessions',binary=TRUE)))
serverId<-serverDetails$value[[1]]$id
```

Navigate to google.

```
getURL(paste0(baseURL,"session/",serverId,"/url"),
       customrequest="POST",
       httpheader=c('Content-Type'='application/json;charset=UTF-8'),
       postfields=toJSON(list(url="http://www.google.com")))
```

get the id of the search box

```
elementDetails<-fromJSON(rawToChar(getURLContent(paste0(baseURL,"session/",serverId,"/element"),
       customrequest="POST",
       httpheader=c('Content-Type'='application/json;charset=UTF-8'),
       postfields=toJSON(list(using="xpath",value="//*[@id=\"gbqfq\"]")),binary=TRUE))
       )

elementId<-elementDetails$value
```

search for a subject matter

```
rawToChar(getURLContent(paste0(baseURL,"session/",serverId,"/element/",elementId,"/value"),
       customrequest="POST",
       httpheader=c('Content-Type'='application/json;charset=UTF-8'),
       postfields=toJSON(list(value=list("\uE009","a","\uE009",'\b','Selenium api in R')))
       ,binary=TRUE))
```

return the search html

```
googData<-fromJSON(rawToChar(getURLContent(paste0(baseURL,"session/",serverId,"/source"),
       customrequest="GET",
       httpheader=c('Content-Type'='application/json;charset=UTF-8'),
       binary=TRUE
       ))
       )
```

get the suggested links

```
gxml<-htmlParse(googData$value)
urls<-unname(xpathSApply(gxml,"//*[@class='l']/@href"))
```

close the session

```
getURL(paste0(baseURL,"session/",serverId),
       customrequest="DELETE",
       httpheader=c('Content-Type'='application/json;charset=UTF-8')
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to scrap soccer matches tables of every single round but dont know how to do, I do appreciate if you're willing to shade me a light...
[Using R to connect Selenium-Server-Standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321739/using-r-to-call-selenium-server-standalone-function-library)

```
elementDetails<-fromJSON(rawToChar(getURLContent(paste0(baseURL,"session/",serverId,"/element"),
   customrequest="POST",
   httpheader=c('Content-Type'='application/json;charset=UTF-8'),
   postfields=toJSON(list(using="xpath",value="//*[@id="Match_Table"]")),binary=TRUE))
   )

elementId<-elementDetails$value
```

Answer (score 0):

The package [relenium](http://lluisramon.github.io/relenium/) (Selenium for R) has been recently developed, importing selenium through the rJava package. It is mainly proposed for webscraping. Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers.

Answer (score 0):

Now, the R package RSelenium exists and can be used as follows :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/")
```